# Search for Specific Character in a String - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i have come across the below Scenario,

i have a Column name Broker_name the few Values in it are `'tpt Broker','Mark iii', 'Davidtpt'`

Final Output for these values should be `'TPT Broker', 'Mark III','Davidtpt'` basically i need to CAPS few predefined value in a String Say **TPT** that comes with trailing spaces, Roman Letters etc..

so i have created a Lookup Table which Has

```
Column1 Column2
tpt      TPT
iii      III
```

could you please let me know how i can check if specifc Characters is present in a string  and then do a lookup on the table. based on that?

Comment: An interesting challenge. I would cross join to the lookup table and use a custom aggregate function to perform the replace. A bit cumbersome, maybe someone comes up with something smarter...

Comment: Strictly speaking, you have broken the 1NF. I'd look into ways to normalize the database (split the field to atomic constituents). After that, your task should be achievable by a fairly straightforward JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I managed to deal with it with a little help of a MODEL clause:

```
SELECT id, broker_name FROM (
  SELECT id, broker_name, rn, val, replacement
  FROM brokers CROSS JOIN (SELECT rownum AS rn, val, replacement FROM lookup)
  MODEL
    PARTITION BY (id)
    DIMENSION BY (rn)
    MEASURES (val, replacement, broker_name)
    RULES (
      broker_name[ANY] = regexp_replace(nvl(broker_name[CV()-1], broker_name[CV()]),
                                        '(^|.*\W)' || val[CV()] || '(\W.*|$)',
                                        '\1' || replacement[CV()] || '\2')
    )
)
WHERE rn = (SELECT count(*) FROM lookup)
ORDER BY id, broker_name;
```

Basically it does the following:

1. Numbers the items in the lookup table
2. Performs a cross join between brokers and lookup
3. For each broker it iterates through the lookup values and makes the replacement (the somewhat weird regular expression ensures that only whole words are replaced)
4. Finally it takes the final row for every broker only, which contains the value after all replacements have been made

Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2944f/1).

Comment: Hello Kombajin,
when i tried with this Data "Mark iii/tpt" it didnt worked.

Fiddle here :- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/586f0/1

Comment: It's because of '/' and I used just space (\s) as word separator. But we can also use any non-alphanumeric (\W), check out the updated query (also fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/586f0/4)

Comment: The Process seems to be running for a Long time. Also we need to do the similar look up on another column can we able to combine this in attached query?  Considering 30,000 records in source table and 8 rows in the Look up Table. i think the process might eat up the time. is there any other options available? like Using Cursor.

Comment: To transform another column simply specify it as another measure and add second rule to the model clause. Regarding performance: on my laptop 30k records got processed in 20s. If you've got only 8 fixed replacement rules, you can always hardcode them instead of having a lookup table, it will be MUCH faster - for the price of flexibility of course.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit difficult, since it needs to be case insensitive (for things like `iIi` or `tpT`). Normally, you'd just use UPPER() but you want to preserve the case of the rest of the columns.  It also has to replace MANY different "incorrect" letters.  And lastly, you don't want anything like `xxxtpt` to be picked up, which is difficult if you can't go by spaces (since it could be at the beginning or end).  I'm not sure what your end goal is.  I can think of two:

1. You just want a Query to format the results correctly.
2. You want a to update any values that contain this.

Either way, this is the simplest solution I can come up with (though remedial).  You'll have to account for all incorrect case combinations (ex: `tpt, tpT, tPt, tPT, Tpt, TPt`).  It's a little brute force, but for lack of time and simplicity (especially if it is only a few cases) this would work:

Code:

```
Select
Trim(
  Replace(
  Replace(
  Replace(
  Replace(
  Replace(
  --note the ' ' are added so we can search for a isolated instance of
  --' tpt ' at the beginning or end of lines, as well as inbetween
  -- these space get Trim()'d at in the end of processing everything.
  Replace(' ' || test_t.text || ' ', ' tpt ', ' TPT ')
                                   , ' tpT ', ' TPT ')
                                   , ' tPt ', ' TPT ')
                                   --etc...
                                   , ' iii ', ' III ')
                                   --etc...
                                   , ' Iii ', ' III ')
                                   , ' IIi ', ' III ')
)
as text

--poor man's way of creating test tables
From
(
    Select 'tpt Broker' as text From dual UNION ALL
    Select 'Mark iii'   as text From dual UNION ALL
    Select 'Davidtpt'   as text From dual 
) test_t
```

Results:

```
TPT Broker
Mark III
Davidtpt
```

This is pretty much the poor man's way.  I'm sure there's better solutions if this is a long term problem, but if your data clean up is easy, this might work.  You could also try using `REGEXP_REPLACE`, or some combo of `INSTR`.  If I think of something better, I'll update this post.

EDIT:

Oi, I knew there had to be a better way.  Using REGEXP_REPLACE simplifies this a lot.  I wasn't able to get the 'case insensitive' query to work (probably overlooking something).  Same methodology, but here's an actual decent solution:

```
Select
    Trim(
        REGEXP_REPLACE(
        REGEXP_REPLACE(
          ' ' || text || ' '  ,  ' [tT][pP][tT] ', ' TPT ')
                              ,  ' [iI][iI][iI] ', ' III ')
        ) as text
From
(
    Select 'tPt Broker' as text From dual UNION ALL
    Select 'Mark iii'   as text From dual UNION ALL
    Select 'Davidtpt'   as text From dual 
) test_t
```